# Create Legend in Java

Tags: java, swing

[image: See the white space in the border]

I am trying to make a design to my java app and I want to make 2 groups I have already done creating 2 groups using JPanel but I am trying to make a legend design type. Now here is my question is there a way to make the overflow of the JPanel visible?

Take a look at the white space in the border of the jpanel there is a jlabel there but its content are out of bound of the panel I want to show them.

here is my code:

```
package myproject;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private JLabel jlabel1, jlabel2, lbtitle1, lbtitle2;
private JTextArea lbresult;
private JPanel layout, group1, group2;
private JButton btnlogin;
private JTextField jtxemail, jtxpass;

public GUI() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super("This is my interface");
    setSize(500,420);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    doDrawing();
    add(layout, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
private void doDrawing() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    layout = new JPanel();
    layout.setLayout(null);
    layout.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    layout.setSize(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

    group1 = createGroup(group1, 0, 15, layout.getWidth() * 50/100, 50);

    lbtitle1 = new JLabel("Email");
    lbtitle1.setBounds(10, -15, 100, 30);
    lbtitle1.setOpaque(true);
    lbtitle1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    //create label1:
    jlabel1 = new JLabel("Email: ");
    jlabel1.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 30);

    //create textfield1:
    jtxemail = new JTextField();
    jtxemail.setBounds(120, 10, 100, 30);

    //add objects for the group:
    group1.add(lbtitle1);
    group1.add(jlabel1);
    group1.add(jtxemail);

    layout.add(group1);
}

private JPanel createGroup(JPanel group, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
      group = new JPanel();
      group.setLayout(null);
      group.setBounds(x, y, 0, 0);
      group.setSize(width, height);
      group.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
      group.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY, 1, false));
      return group;
   }
}
```

Comment: `"....but I am trying to make a legend design type."` -- can you explain in fairly good detail just what you mean by this. What legend design? What example do you have?

Comment: `"Now here is my question is there a way to make the overflow of the JPanel visible?"` -- and what do you mean by "overflow"? And how is your current code supposed to work? How is it not working? Please tell the details of your problem, else we may not understand it

Comment: Also, while null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.

Comment: like when you use the <legend></legend> in html it cut a piece of the border and put a string in it.

Comment: my question is just for design so my code mus show a label, a text field inside a box and a title for that box

Comment: Thanks for the update. Please [edit] your question and give even more detail + images to show what you mean.

Comment: I added an image see the white space in the border of the jpanel there is a jlabel there I want the word to show up that is the overflow I was talking about when the element get out of the bounds of the jpanel

Comment: Your problem would likely go away if you avoided use of null layouts

Comment: what layout should I use?

Comment: You say you want something that works the same as [`<legend> tag in html`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_legend.asp)? If so then just give your panel a [TitledBorder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this using a combination of layouts. For instance if you wanted a single column of data for input, then the overall layout could be a `GridLayout(0, 1)`, creating a grid of one column and variable number of rows. Then the rows themselves would be made of a JPanel that uses, say GridBagLayout. Something like so:

[image]

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI2 extends JPanel {
    private static final String[][] LABELS = {
            {"E-Mail", "E-Mail Address"},
            {"Phone", "Phone Number"},
            {"Address", "Street Address"},
            {"City", "City"},
            {"State", "State"} };
    private static final int TXT_FIELD_COLS = 15;
    private Map<String, JTextField> labelFieldMap = new HashMap<>();

    public GUI2() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        for (String[] label : LABELS) {
            add(createLegend(label));
        }
    }

    private JPanel createLegend(String[] label) {
        JLabel jLabel = new JLabel(label[1]);
        JTextField txtField = new JTextField(TXT_FIELD_COLS);
        labelFieldMap.put(label[0], txtField);

        JPanel legendPanel = new JPanel();
        legendPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(label[0]));
        legendPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        int anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        int fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        int ins = 3;
        Insets insets = new Insets(ins, ins, ins, 3* ins);
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, anchor, fill, insets, 0, 0);
        legendPanel.add(jLabel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 0.0;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        legendPanel.add(txtField, gbc);
        return legendPanel;
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        GUI2 mainPanel = new GUI2();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: I have used the titled border that is what I want

Comment: `legendPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(label[0]));`

Comment: yes I took it from you and I said thank you for it :)